# How to swap ~ and § keys on Catalina?

Tags: keyboard, catalina

I have a Rapoo 9000M set and its key next to the right shift is switched with the key in the top left corner (usually §±).
Keyboard assistant doesn't recognise this keyboard.
Is there any config file I can modify to get these two characters switched back?
(I use Karabiner so I accept Karabiner-based solutions if they work with *multiple* languages.)

Comment: It's the key next to *left* shift the Mac uses to recognise the keyboard; which is either Z for US ANSI, ` for English ISO or a variety of other things for non-English. The only pic I can find of a 9000M is a Windows ANSI layout, with Z right of Shift. [§± next to 1 is English ISO, `~ is US ANSI] A picture might help.

Comment: Presumably the machine thinks your keyboard is ansi instead of iso?  Some possible fixes:  https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: Yes, both of you are right, the Mac gets puzzled because the ` code is mapped to the wrong key on the device, on Mac (weirdly enough, in Windows it works correctly). So, the Mac keyboard assistant goes belly up.:) But, as Tom also wrote, it can be fixed with Karabiner.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution with [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).
It works correctly, even if I switch keyboard layout to a different language.

Steps:

1. I checked the key name for `~` and `§` with Karabiner EventViewer (can be accessed from the karabiner menu).
2. I looked up my product_id and vendor_id in the Karabiner log (Preferences > Log tab).
3. I edited the json file in `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/`, adding the following to the `"rules"` list:

```
    {
          "description": "~ -> §",
          "manipulators": [
            {
              "type": "basic",
              "from": {
                "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde"
              },
              "to": [
                {
                  "key_code": "non_us_backslash"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [{
            "type": "device_if",
            "identifiers": [
            {
                "vendor_id": 9390,
                "product_id": 8211,
                "description": "Rapoo keyboard"
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "description": "§ -> ~",
          "manipulators": [
            {
              "type": "basic",
              "from": {
                "key_code": "non_us_backslash"
              },
              "to": [
                {
                  "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [{
            "type": "device_if",
            "identifiers": [
            {
                "vendor_id": 9390,
                "product_id": 8211,
                "description": "Rapoo keyboard"
            }]
          }]
        }
```

4. I added the two new rules to the Complex modifications.
5. Quit Karabiner and launched it again.

References:
https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/conditions/device/

Comment: I'll second a recommendation for Karabiner!